# select multiple item from sqlite database in c

Tags: c, sqlite, embedded-linux

I'm trying to query sqlite in c ,
previously I open and inserted some items to the database successfully(return SQLITE_OK),When I query total data ("SELECT * FROM TRANS_TABLE ...") I can retrieve my inserted data successfully but when I try to query by a specific item, I do not receive any data,is there any thing wrong with my code ?

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM TRANS_TABLE WHERE F11_STAN = ?";

  cmdStat = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);

  if (cmdStat == SQLITE_OK)
  {
  sqlite3_bind_text( res, 1,( char *)f11, strlen(( char *)f11), 0);
  }
  else
  {
      netLogMsg(( uint8_t*)sqlite3_errmsg(db));
      return ;
  }

  int step = sqlite3_step(res);

  if (step == SQLITE_ROW)
  {
    netLogMsg(( uint8_t *)sqlite3_column_text(res, 0));
    netLogMsg(( uint8_t *)sqlite3_column_text(res, 1));
  }
else if (step == SQLITE_DONE)
{
  //this line is executed !
  netLogMsg(( uint8_t *)sqlite3_errmsg(db));
}
  memcpy( f11, sqlite3_column_text(res, 1), strlen(( const char *)sqlite3_column_text(res, 1)));

  sqlite3_finalize(res);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try binding the id to the prepared statement:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM TRANS_TABLE WHERE F11_STAN = ?1";
cmdStat = sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &res, 0);
sqlite3_bind_int(res, 1, 5);
```

Comment: Thank for Reply, that was a typing mistake, I edited my question and It does not work yet.

Comment: @MHD does it work when you pass an id to the prepared statement `SELECT * FROM TRANS_TABLE WHERE F11_STAN = 5` for example?

Comment: yes it works correctly.

Comment: @MHD lets try binding the id to the prepared statement. I've edited my answer give it a try

Comment: Thanks for follwing up, there is no problem with sqlite3_bind_int functions and I think there is a problem with feeding sqlite3_bind_text

Comment: @MHD nvm just saw it in your code

Comment: whats meaning of nvm? do you mean there is no problem with bind_text function ? when I changed sql = "SELECT * FROM TRANS_TABLE WHERE F11_STAN = 4" or any other constant value and commented bind_text it worked fine, also testing with bind_int is worked too , then Seems there is a problem with bind_text

Comment: @MHD It means never mind, because I was going to suggest you to use `bind_text` but then I saw your function in your code. But since it worked with `"SELECT * FROM TRANS_TABLE WHERE F11_STAN = 4"` that tells me that your id is numeric. If you use bind text, the resulting sql from the prepared statement will look like `"SELECT * FROM TRANS_TABLE WHERE F11_STAN = '4' "` and it won't fetch anything from the db. Bind_text will add the `' '` to make it proper sql. If your `F11_STAN` is numeric, just use bind_int.

Comment: no that is not int, F11_STAN is a TEXT parameter.

Comment: @MHD I see. Well the last think I can think of is that `f11` is not `\0` null terminated.

Comment: As you guess, problem was related to INT/TEXT type , I forgot to enter ' ' during INSERTING values( however I set TEXT type).